# Add 'What's Hot' to additional Discussion Lists

Tags: content-query-web-part, discussion-board, community-site

I'm having trouble trying to leverage the "What's Hot" tab/Popularity column in SharePoint 2013's Discussion List.

I've created a custom content query web part that can filter out discussions from subsites based on Popularity, and it's pulling posts from subsites created using the "Community" template.

By default, the initial Discussion list always has a "What's Hot" tab that displays popular posts. However, I run into problems when I try to create a new Discussion List in the same subsite, which is that there's no "What's Hot" tab on the new Discussion Lists.

[image: Default Discussion with "What's Hot"]

[image: "What's Hot" missing in newly created Discussion List]

As a result, no thread created in the new Discussion List would show up on the content query either.

My question is, how do you get this "What's Hot" tab on additional Discussions List that you added to the subsite? What do I have to do to ensure that Popularity for a Thread is stored and calculated after I turn it on?

Here's a list of additional thing's I've tried/attemped
1) Duplicate the Default Discussion List - can't find an option that lets me export the original
2) I noticed that the newly created Discussion is missing all of the rating columns (under List Settings), but turning them on made no different

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a CQWP, you should be able to use a Content Search Web Part or Search Results Web Part to query all discussion posts from the identified subsites and then use the OOTB sort of popularity.